# Issue with Entity Framework, the table or view does not have a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I have a small crud app in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework, everything works fine, only that I was asked to use a view to add to the crud. In any case this view does not have a primary key and when I want to add the view it jumps to me that error. Is there any way I can fix this without modifying the view?

I attach the example view:

```
create view view_Prueba 
as
    select nombre, garantia, region, sucursal
    from region, prueba
    where idprue = idprue
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the correction, but it is an example, I do not have access to the real view of the server

Answer (score 0):

1. Create view in your db using your select query  Or using EF

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
@"Create view view_Prueba as
select nombre, garantia, region, sucursal
from region, prueba
where idprue=idprue");
```

2. Create the View_Prueba class that contains
   nombre, garantia, region, sucursal properties   { get; private set; }
3. Add this view to your  ef dbcontext

```
public virtual DbQuery<View_Prueba> View_Pruebas { get; set; }

.....


  modelBuilder.Entity<View_Prueba>(e =>
            {
                e.ToView("View_Prueba");
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```

if you use ef  core version less then core 5 try this code

```
public virtual DbQuery<View_Prueba> View_Pruebas { get; set; }

.....
```

Comment: I believe the `.HasNoKey()` functionality is only available in **EF Core** - and I see no signs of the OP mentioning the "Core" version of EF ....

Comment: @marc_s  is correct, I am not using EF Core